# How to create an empty data frame to store alphanumeric data

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

So, I have a .tsv file of human variants. 
I need to store in a `data.frame` all the rows of this file with a precise name and save them in another file. I'm trying with this script:

```
data = read.table(file.choose(), sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
variant = readline("Insert variant:")
store <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(data)))
colnames(store) = colnames(data)
for (i in 1:nrow(data))
 {
  if (data[i,3] == variant)
  {
    store[i,] = as.data.frame(data[i,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   }
 }
```

But because I used a matrix in the `data.frame,` it stores only numeric data, of course. Any ideas of how can I solve this and how can I write the output of the loop directly in a .tsv file?

Comment: Why not use a `list()` and use the list names as your "precise names".

Comment: Are you wanting to keep all of the rows, such that `store` has empty rows?
If discarding the rows would work, maybe all you need is a subset, something like `store<-data[data[[3]]==variant,]`, which simply takes the rows of `data` where the third column matches `variant`.

Comment: @rosscova Thank you very much! This worked perfectly! I'm new in R and didn't think about this simple solution.

Comment: Great! I'll turn it into an answer below.

Comment: @Andre Elrico List was my second choice, I wanted to discover if I can use data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If discarding the rows would work, what you need is a subset, something like:

```
store <- data[ data[[3]] == variant, ]
```

`data[[3]]` here looks at the third column, which we compare to `variant`. So we subset `data` by taking only those rows where that third column matches `variant`.